# XPath get one attribute or another?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I have a Python XML XPath expression `ancestor-or-self::*[@foo]/@foo`, and I need to modify it to get attribute `@foo` if it exists otherwise get attribute `@bar`.

I've tried to use `or` operator similar to condition like `[@foo or @bar]`, but got an expression error.

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

For a correct *`XPath_Prefix`*, this XPath,

- *`XPath_Prefix`*`/@*[name()='foo' or name()='bar'][1]`

will select the `foo` attribute if available; otherwise, the `bar` attribute.